# How to perform particular operation by button click

Tags: django

I want to perform more than 2 operation in single HTML page by button click. In menu bar have 5 options. i.e when i click Home it perform some operation and when i click profile it perform particular operation. I write separate functions for each operation. How to do multiple functions operations for single page.

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})


def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = request.session['username']
            print(first_name)
            test = Profile.objects.filter(first_name=first_name).values()
            for i in test:
                dict1 = i
                return render(request, 'index.html',
                              {'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': dict1['last_name'],
                               'phone_number': dict1['phone_number'], 'email': dict1['email'],
                               'address': dict1['address'], 'image': dict1['image']})
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})

def friends(request):
    friends_obj = Friends.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'friends_obj': friends_obj})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name="home"),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name="profile"),
    path('friends/', views.friends, name="friends"),
]
```

[menu bar look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU6c0.png)I want to perform all operations by clicking menu options.

Answer (score 0):

`def friends(request):` and `def home(request):` are with `Get` method and `def profile(request):` is with `Post` method. so first step we can serate them with `if request.method == "POST"` . for separate process with same method we need attach some flag to process from front-end (Html-javascript and etc) before sending to django view.something like this:
template.html:

```
<form action="/navbar_aggregation" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="type" value="friends" hidden> 
  <!-- other input tag will be here as you need--> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

then you can access to type in view like this. view.py:

```
def navbar_aggregation(request):
    type = request.get.Get("type")  # name of hidden input 
    if (type == "friends"):
        # do same thing like 'def freinds(request)'
    elif(type == "family"):
        # do process for family form
    else :
        # do process for 'def home(request)'
```

so now we know how can seprate method="Get" or method="POST" . so your view will be like this:

view.py:

```
def navbar_aggregation(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
         form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            first_name = request.session['username']
            print(first_name)
            test = Profile.objects.filter(first_name=first_name).values()
            for i in test:
                dict1 = i
                return render(request, 'index.html',
                              {'first_name': first_name, 'last_name': dict1['last_name'],
                               'phone_number': dict1['phone_number'], 'email': 
                                  dict1['email'],
                               'address': dict1['address'], 'image': dict1['image']})       
   else : # we are in method="GET"
      type = request.get.Get("type")  # name of hidden input 
      if(type == "friends"):
              friends_obj = Friends.objects.all()
              return render(request, 'index.html', {'friends_obj': friends_obj})
      elif(type == "form"):
            form = ProfileForm()
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
      elif(type == "foo"):
            # do something for foo's form 
            return something
      else:  # for sure it should be home's request because haven't any tag for "type"
         return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

dear friend i'm new in django too so i think my answer code have some bug, but maybe help you .I answered your question because i see not any pro developer not answering your question .

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm also new to django. I will try.